# How to set bottom margin using the resume class with [margin,line]

Tags: margins, cv, resume

I really like the way my resume looks using the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[line,margin]{resume}

\begin{document}

\topmargin=-0.5in
```

However, I have a huge margin at the bottom of the page. I tried using the geometry package along with margin=0.5in, but I get an error, unless I remove ``margin" from the document class declaration. However, removing it fundamentally changes the way the document looks. I'd rather keep the document looking the same (and hopefully, not having to recreate it using a different document class) as it does now, and just fix the bottom margin.

Is there a way of using the above declarations and making the bottom margin smaller?

Answer (score 26):

Have you tried using the `geometry` package?

A simple way to configure your margins with the package:

```
\usepackage[bottom=0.5in]{geometry}
```

You can set the `top`, `right` and `left` margins independently using comma-separted keyvals:

```
\usepackage[bottom=0.5in,top=0.8in]{geometry}
```

or even a single one for all the margins if you want to modify them:

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have tried doing that, but I get an error because of the use of "margin" in \documentclass[line,margin]{resume}. Removing it from the document class declaration and using the geometry package changes the way the section titles look. So I prefer to keep margin in the declaration and figure out a different way of fixing the bottom one.

Answer (score 10):

You can change the `margin` option to other name to avoid name conflict with geometry package.

If you are using the res.cls by Michael DeCorte, find the line:

```
\DeclareOption{margin}{\@margintrue}
```

Change the option name to something else, for example

```
\DeclareOption{resmargin}{\@margintrue}
```

and correspondingly update the option

```
\documentclass[line,resmargin]{resume}
```

With these changes, you can use geometry package to your heart's content.

If you are using some other .cls, do something similar. Just change margin option to another name.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the small response. Although this is kind of a hack which someone already suggested. So here it goes. In the res.cls file there is a textheight field

```
\textheight 9.5in
```

Changing this textheight field value will allow more text to be filled in your resume page. Until you get a definitive answer you can vary this value to reduce the whitespace in bottom margin. I am also searching for a less hack solution :)

Comment: Could you elaborate by means of an example? Are you referring to the `\textheight` length (not the field)?

Comment: At the moment this is a comment only. I tend to `Looks Ok`, hoping the OP will improve his answer

Comment: I hope you did `\setlength{\textheight}{9in}` in your preamble and did not change file `res.cls`.

Comment: Thanks Johannes_B, I was changing the res.cls file only. Will make that correction. Not a very latex savvy person :)

Answer (score 3):

A Brute Force method is to adjust the text height using the following code

```
\setlength{textheight}{674+somevalue pt}
```

See this page for reference https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Page_size_and_margins#Paper_size.2C_orientation_and_margins

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We usually tend to provide self-contained answers in form of minimal working examples.