# Reduce page margins using the res document class

Tags: margins, cv, resume

In order to make my resume more dense and get more content on a page, I wanted to reduce page margins.
I had been struggling with this issue for a long time and couldn't find any good complete solution online.

However, after several pitfalls, I've managed to resolve all problems now and thought I'd share my solution and maybe help others struggling with the same.

*Feel free to edit and improve*

Comment: Yes, readability should not suffer. However, my document has section titles shiftet to the left (similar to this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uuPKw.png), which takes some space and makes lines shorter than usual.

Answer (score 2):

*This guide assumes you use a file `res.cls` and are able to modify it*

### Reduce margins

The geometry package helps reducing page margins, e.g. like

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
```

(Default margin is 1 inch.)

However, this will raise errors when compiling, because `res` and `geometry` both use an option named `margin`. As [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154148/26069) suggests, this can be resolved by changing the line (in `res.cls`)

```
\DeclareOption{margin}{\@margintrue}
```

to

```
\DeclareOption{resmargin}{\@margintrue}
```

and in your document

```
\documentclass[line,resmargin]{res}
```

### Increase content size

Now, content will be positioned closer to the upper left corner, but still remain in the same box, i.e. produce more visual margin on the right/bottom.
To resolve this, `\textwidth` and `\textheight` need to be adjusted.

They can be overridden by

```
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\textheight}{10in}
```

If this doesn't work, check if those values are overridden later in your file.

Comment: Silly question, where is this res.cls file located? I have been dealing with this margin issue for 2 hours and it is driving me crazy!

Comment: It's usually automatically loaded from the package repo, but you can just download the source file from [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/res) and place it in the same directory as your .tex file, then go on and edit it.